# Did Kakashi know Rin sacrificed herself, or did he think it was all an accident?

Tags: naruto

This always confused me, and I have not seen this addressed anywhere. We know that after the incident where Rin dies, Kakashi blames himself for her death and goes in a downward spiral.

Later, he meets Obito again in the Fourth Shinobi World War, and Obito reveals the truth to the audience about how Rin died. Namely, that she had the tailed beast sealed into her, and that it was part of the plan to lure the beast back to the village and cause destruction. We find out that she jumped in front of Kakashi's chidori to kill herself in order to save her village.

Kakashi seems visibly shocked at this news. So, am I right to think that until that point, **Kakashi did not know the truth about Rin's sacrifice?**

On another point, it seems to explain why no one in the village praised Rin as a hero for her sacrifice, right?